# Slide background image ReactJS | CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a horizontal image that I want to use as a background. I want to change the position of the image depending on the argument passed to the function. My image:

[image]

My code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Background from '../images/background_image.jpg';

class MoveImage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 1
     }
  }

    const bgSlide = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
    };

    moveBGImage=(id)=>{
        //slide the image depending on the id
        //so if id=2, the image should slide from screen1 to screen2
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div style = { bgSlide } >

                <button
                    onClick = this.moveBGImage(this.state.counter+1)
                >
                    Click Me

                </button>

            </div>

            )
    }


}


export default MoveImage;
```

So if the counter is 2, I want to show screen2 part of the image. And screen1 should slide left and screen2 slide in from right. Can this be done in React?

Comment: Does the `<div>` have a fixed height/width ratio?

Comment: No, there is no fixed height-width ratio. But I can try by giving a ratio to understand how it works.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cloud-vv3ob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with CSS [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [screen, setScreen] = React.useState(1)
  const toggleScreen = () => setScreen(s => s > 3 ? 1 : s + 1)
  return (
    <div className={`screen nr${screen}`} onClick={toggleScreen} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.screen {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/72bFV.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.screen.nr2 {
  background-position: 33.33% 0;
}
.screen.nr3 {
  background-position: 66.67% 0;
}
.screen.nr4 {
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I used the image from question, which does not have exact 1/4 parts, so the red lines do not align exactly.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Except for the `useState` part, I somewhat understood the logic. Could you please breakdown the `toggleScreen` function? Thank you so much

Comment: when clicked, it will set `screen` in the next render to 2, then to 3, 4, 1, 2, ... see React Hooks documentation about [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for more details - it's similar to [`this.setState((state) => ...)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)